# How do you prove that an estimator is linear?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

Consider a no intercept simple linear regression model $Y_i = \beta{X_i} + u_i$ This is the "true" model, which is unknown to the researcher.

Now consider an estimator $\beta^* = \frac{\bar Y}{\bar X}$. The researcher has decided for some unknown reason to use this estimator to regress Y on X using a sample from the true model above (perhaps calling it a model is wrong?).  But, she first wants to re-assure herself that this is indeed a linear estimator, so that she can begin the work of showing that it is B.L.U.E - The Best Linear Unbiased Estimator.

What strategy would you recommend to prove that this is a linear estimator *without* using matrix notation, but only summation and expectation operators?  That means, make no references to scalars and vectors.

The reason for this restriction is for the answer to comply with the baseline knowledge offered in many introductory linear regression textbooks in econometrics, in which all proofs are completed using only summation notation (Including the Gauss-Markov Theorem for the Classic Linear Regression Model).

To set a baseline definition of a linearity, consider a simple finite case of an estimator \hat\beta:

$\hat\beta = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=3}{a_ix_i} = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 $

Comment: In simple model, $X$ is not considered random. Accordingly, your estimator has a random variable only in numerator which is a *linear* sum of the random variable $Y_i$.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a good explanation. How would you write that linear relationship in a mathematical statement in the context of the specified model and estimator?

Comment: I don't understand that comment: you already have written an explicitly linear function of the observations $Y,$ understanding that $\bar Y$ is a linear combination.

Comment: OK, I can see why you are confused.  The thing is , to say that something is a linear function, it must have a mathematical definition.   From that mathematical definition and with some assumptions you should be able to provide a PROOF.   So as a starting point, what is the definition of a linear function in pure math language?

Comment: Linear in pure math language: $T(au+bv)=aT(u)+bT(v)$ for scalars $a,b$ and vectors $u,v$

Comment: This pure math language would not make senses to someone who is working through a 400 page tome on linear regression that is only using summation notation.  I tried to rework my question above to clarify this.   I feel like everyone is getting fooled by this question, thinking the answer is trivial, but I think the proof is quite tricky, or so I'm told.

Comment: The proof really is quite trivial, so there's clearly some kind of misunderstanding here. To help get at it, would you please share the most promising proof approach you've tried? This will help us better understand where you're coming from.

Comment: This question is typical of a 1st course in econometrics.  Students are learning to identify BLUE estimators  so the teacher can then begin to dismantle the standard assumptions of the Guass Markov theorem, eg. by introducing Heteroskasdicity.  Hence, the professors love to offer these types of "weird estimator" problems to force students to work through the math of breaking an estimator into the random and non-random components (in order to prove unbiasedness using estimation operator). I am one of those students, so I'm afraid I have no answer, and not sure how to start.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your question to include the definition of linearity that you prefer?

Comment: I'm starting to feel guilty that I'm causing so much trouble.   I think I will supply my best answer now, as I have worked on this for some time.  Please correct any errors.

Answer (score 2):

I belive this solution only works if we assume sample values of X are non stochastic, and constant across samples.

$\beta^* = \frac{\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}}$

$= \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{Y_i}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum{X_i}} = \frac{\sum{Y_i}}{\sum{X_i}}  $

$= \left(
\frac{1}{\sum{X_i}} \right)\sum{y_i}$

$Let \ g = \left(
\frac{1}{\sum{X_i}} \right)$

$\implies g\sum{y_i} = \sum{g\cdot{y_i}}$

Comment: That looks exactly right. Another way to think about it is that your same proof strategy goes through to prove that the sample mean $\bar{Y}$ is linear. With that, the linearity of your estimator follows from a simple property of linearity: a constant times a linear function is also linear.

Comment: That's even better!